# Else doesnt work in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have big problem with my code. In loop *while* working only first argument *if*. *Else* doesn't work... Here is a code :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM house1 WHERE week = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($row['house'] == $q)
    {
        echo '<img src="house2.gif"/>';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo '<img src="house1.gif"/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: the code snippet seems fine. If the if-statement is false, then the code goes to the else block. If it's "true", then only the if-block will be handled.

Comment: you should check with your $q variable if its really equal to $row['house']

Comment: if you show what is this $q and what house column properties , se we can see

Comment: Why would week and house have same value $q??